# Creating docker containers for dev and prod with multiple postgres databases

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create 2 docker containers one for dev and one for prod using `docker-compose`. The two containers should be linked to separate postgres databases.
I tried the following, but it seems to create just one container and one database everytime.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: myinstance-postgres-database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= dbpass
      - POSTGRES_DB= ProductionDB
   ports:
   - 127.17.0.1:5432:5432
   volumes:
   - myinstance-postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: service/platform:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: prod-app
    environment:
      DB_SETUP: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: "postgresql"
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USER: "dbuser"
      DB_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
      DB_NAME: "ProductionDB"
      DB_WAIT: 10
    ports:
    - 8443:8443
    volumes:
    - myinstance-postgres-git:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/git
    depends_on:
    - db

volumes:
  myinstance-postgres-db:
  myinstance-postgres-git:
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: myinstancedev-postgres-database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= dbpass
      - POSTGRES_DB= DevDB
   ports:
   - 127.17.0.1:5432:5432
   volumes:
   - myinstancedev-postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: service/platform:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: dev-app
    environment:
      DB_SETUP: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: "postgresql"
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USER: "dbuser"
      DB_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
      DB_NAME: "DevDB"
      DB_WAIT: 10
    ports:
    - 8444:8443
    volumes:
    - myinstancedev-postgres-git:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/git
    depends_on:
    - db

volumes:
  myinstancedev-postgres-db:
  myinstancedev-postgres-git:
```

Then I run :

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```

as a result I have one container which is dev-app and only one database is created.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run both of them together use

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p prod up -d && sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml -p dev up -d
```

When you pass multiple files in the same `docker-compose` command, it does not create separate containers as you'd like. It instead merges them. Check [Share Compose configurations between files and projects](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files)

Also note, you may have `PORT` conflict errors in the host. Because in both the compose files you are exposing the same ports `5432` and `8443`

My output with 2 alpine postgres images on different ports.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
74a8e5a8fad0        postgres:alpine     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:5430->5432/tcp   prod_web_1
23f2b995d499        postgres:alpine     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds            0.0.0.0:5431->5432/tcp   dev_web_1
```

Also, do consider using [env files for compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Done that but doesn't change anything !

Comment: I made an edit in the main command. You can try and see again if it works for you.

Comment: Still merging. as a result I have only the dev container

Comment: Strange. Because that command creates 2 different processes. I'll see if I can do a POC with postgres on 2 different ports

Comment: Okay thank you. Please let me know if you get the same issue

Comment: The latest edit will work. I've tested it as well and posted the output.

Comment: Thank you that works. But the database container keeps restarting giving me that message ```Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser.```